# htaccess allow navigation through inside folder not parent folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication

Folder Structure

```
A 
|- AA
|- AB
\- AC
```

I DO NOT want to allow anyone to enter into A without User Authentication. Although, I WANT to be able to allow ANYONE to view contents in AC

How could I do this, using my .htaccess ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to create 3 files:

One .htaccess-file in the folder "A"

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected Area"
AuthUserFile path/to/.htpasswd-file/relative/to/your/server's/root/directory
require valid-user
```

The .htpasswd-file (also in folder "A") with the username and password

And one .htaccess-file in the folder "AC" to exclude this folder from the protection:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
Satisfy any
```

Especially for the .htpasswd-file I would use an online generator like this one: http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/password/

Comment: You mean 2 .htaccess files right ? Or what is the third for ?

Comment: Yes, 2 .htaccess files. The first in the folder "A", the second in the folder "AC"